# GPG KeyID when listing packets and into keyring

Tags: encryption, gnupg

When I check file packets with

```
gpg --list-packets file.gpg
```

it shows that file is encrypted by some key with ID of 16 symbols.  But when I try to check this key in my keyring using

```
gpg --list-keys
```

or with `--with-fingerprint` or `--list-signatures`, I can't find this ID in a list.

How could I match ID of key that encrypted a file with ID of a key in my keyring?  Where can I find the same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encrypted packet is actually referencing a *subkey* that is marked as encryption-capable.
Use `--with-subkey-fingerprint` to see them.

(The same PGP key or PGP certificate can in fact have multiple encryption-capable subkeys, so if the packet used the main key's ID, it would be ambiguous.)

Also, GPG itself can find the main key for you, when given the subkey ID or fingerprint – just specify it as the parameter to `gpg --list-keys`.

Comment: And of the subkey is expired, one need to use `--list-options show-unusable-subkeys` to show it.